# How to trigger a GA hitType=data via GTM?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I need to trigger a GA hit of type data and I need to do this via GTM.

The problem I am having is I don't see a hit type data in the list of events in the GA template in GTM.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should answer the question: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits

I don't see the data hit type there, but you're free to try it out. I think data may be used by google optimize. I've seen adswerve reacting to google optimize events like data type.

Anyway, if you sure the ga function accepts the data hit type, you can use custom code and call the function directly as it's shown in the doc.

Comment: Exactly, It's mostly used with Optimize to place the user in the correct variant and it should be triggered automatically by Optimize itself.